# Trying to return a virtual attribute through User serializer in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I have a virtual attribute defined in my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_writer :tdee
  attr_reader :tdee
  include Authentication
  has_many :examples
  has_many :meals, inverse_of: :user

  def tdee
    if gender == 'f'
      bmr = 655 + (9.6 * (weight * 0.453592)) + (1.8 * (height * 2.54)) - (4.7 * age)
    elsif gender == 'm'
      bmr = 66 + (13.7 * (weight * 0.453592)) + (5 * (height * 2.54)) - (6.8 * age)
    end
    tdee = bmr * activity_level
  end
end
```

I am able to access it in my rails console, and in my controller. I would like it to be included in json when I index/show users, so I assume I have to edit my user serializer. Currently my serializer looks like the default generated by my migration:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :height, :weight, :age, :activity_level, :gender

end
```

I have tried things like:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :height, :weight, :age, :activity_level, :gender, :tdee

  def tdee
    tdee = @user.tdee
  end

end
```

I consistently get

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `tdee' for nil:NilClass):
  app/serializers/user_serializer.rb:6:in `tdee'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:48:in `index'
```

Some other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324492/active-model-serializer-with-virtual-attribute-rails-4) talk about using to_json, but I'm not sure how to implement this in my context seeing as I'm not building the user info using that method.

EDIT:

As suggested below I needed to user object.tdee. After I updated this, I was still getting a no method error because I had nil values for the attributes needed to calculate the virtual. Updating these solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using @user you need to use object in your serializer. Note that serializers do not see instance variables set by controllers

```
def tdee
  object.tdee
end
```

you do not need tdee =. Check this blog post http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/07/23/using-activemodel-serializers-to-build-great-json-interfaces/

Comment: this returns `NoMethodError (undefined method '*' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/user.rb:15:in 'tdee'
  app/serializers/user_serializer.rb:6:in 'tdee'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:48:in 'index'`

Comment: Am I able to define my virtual attribute in my serializer? That way I can avoid it no seeing my definition in my model.

Comment: When you run rails console can return value of tdee? Try to fetch a record with user = User.last and then user.tdee. Does it work? Serializers can return custom methods using object.method_name but it looks like from the error is that you are trying to multiply * with nill value which you cannot do. I would say check the method inside your User model class and make sure that there are not nil values in your formulas.

Comment: So it works through rails console. But there is only one user with the data set needed to calculate TDEE. So you're suggesting that the fact that my other two users don't have this data set, when I use a show action (accessing all users) the missing data is throwing the error?

Comment: Yes if you are serializing them all like in for example index action. So you will need to add logic in your model that does not generate exception for example . For quick testing in your serializer wrap object.tdee inside begin rescue block but just ot see if it is working. Then what you could do is to refactor def tdee in your User model and implement safe validation like if self.width && self.height....etc

Comment: I have an ember question up. noticed you seem to know ember. @Mirza